# React does not recognize the `anyTouched` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

i have [redux form](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/) inside my [reactstrap modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-reactstrap-modal).when my popup appear,console log show below warning.without Form it's working charm.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with 'anytouched'?

Comment: either you should remove it or replace it with `anytouched`

Answer (score 1):

You have a component say it's name is **CustomComponent** that retuns something like this

```
<div>
  <Form {...this.props}>
   <p> this.props.pText </p>
   <Button>I'm a button named {this.props.buttonName} </Button>
  </Form>
</div>
```

and when you render it in another file you do this

```
<CustomComponent pText="hi" buttonName="randomName">
```

so what happens is you are passing the `buttomName`, `pText` to your `Form` which doesn't accept `pText`, `buttonName` (remember, Your button &

accept those props but not the form itself, so the virtual react DOM guesses that the prop is not for react, so it must be a real DOM prop & doesn't know what to do with it, to solve the problem, simply remove the `{...this.props}`

Answer (score 0):

this is a result of how React is handling custom vs predefined DOM attributes -> see here
https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html